# SEO View Page using OG delta or Url as Contextual Filter

Tags: organic-groups

I've been trying to use Delta of OG and/or Group Url to use it as a Contextual Filter in a Page View. I want to show the content of the group filtered for the corresponding group. If' now my Group Urls are like "grupo/group-name", I'd like to filter that Groups posts like "posts/grupo/group-name", but all I can do is filter by Gid, like "posts/grupo/1", which is obviously not SEO.

Is there a relation or anything I can use to achieve this? I saw I could print out the url of the Group node as a Field in a View, which is what I'd need for "posts/grupo/group-name", because the url of the node I print is "grupo/group-name". Anyway, there's no Contextual Filter I can apply with that option.

Any thoughts?

THANKS!!!!